# Does Apple allow apps that have statically linked Swift libraries?

Tags: swift, static-linking, appstore-approval

I know that Swift libraries can be statically linked, but I'd heard that linking in Swift would cause Apple's private API detectors to prevent it from going into the App Store? Is this true?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not Apple customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/2988).

Answer (score 0):

Found a link on an Apple Forum; hopefully it helps you, I haven't yet submitted anything to the AppStore yet.

But overall, seems like it's possibly more trouble than it's worth. If you get denied, you're possibly then going to spend time rebuilding/reworking.

Seems to be one point brought up, is to ensure you've added all files needed to compile your App, in your submission.

*Link below:*

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94488

Answer (score 0):

**As of Xcode 9 beta 4, Xcode natively supports static libraries with Swift sources.** but You have to use dynamic lib

Here is how Apple describes their dynamic framework:

Two important factors that determine the performance of apps are their launch times and their memory footprints. Reducing the size of an app’s executable file and minimizing its use of memory once it’s launched make the app launch faster and use less memory once it’s launched. Using dynamic libraries instead of static libraries reduces the executable file size of an app. They also allow apps to delay loading libraries with special functionality only when they’re needed instead of at launch time. This feature contributes further to reduced launch times and efficient memory use.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/OverviewOfDynamicLibraries.html

Comment: It takes ~150ms to load swift dylibs at startup on the iPhone 7 :)